# cross thread error while using thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use thread and close my form after some operations.But I get a cross thread error .solutions?

```
     new System.Threading.Thread(s =>
        {  
            Close;   }).Start();
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to but the close(); statement in this for WPF

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
     // Code to run on the UI thread.
});
```

and in this for WinForms

```
this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
{
    // Code to run on the UI thread.
});
```